# how to pass url of a website in Hashmap in android

Tags: java, android

I am building online music application in android and I am using HashMap. 
it has method method ie:-

```
hashmap.put<String,URL>
```

example:

```
 HashMap<String,URL> urlHashMap=new HashMap<String,URL>();

 urlHashMap.put("Manali Trance",http://newmp3mad.com/128-734892s/Manali%20Trance.mp3);
```

It is not allowing me to put URL.
Please someone help.

Answer (score 3):

Use Uri (or URL) type for your hashmap types : so it will be String/Uri

```
    HashMap<String, Uri> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
    hashmap.put("Queen", Uri.parse("http://queen.com/you.mp3"));
```

*Import information : use Uri from android.net*

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use your URL as a string literal like so:

```
urlHashMap.put("Manali Trance","http://newmp3mad.com/128-734892s/Manali%20Trance.mp3");
```

Java doesn't have URL literal types. Whether using a string or parse as a URI depends entirely on what you're trying to do.

Comment: A good practice is to have object **type representing the data it contains**. So having a url in a String is ok, but a `URL` in an `Url` object or in an `Uri` is **better**

Comment: Which is better cannot be said generically, but depends entirely on what he's trying to do with it, which he didn't tell us. Mute point to argue about anyway.